# To increase size of Radio Buttons and Checkboxes in Mozilla Browser

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

I have used some Checkboxes and Radio bUttons in my webpage. On zooming size of Checkboxes, Radio bUttons and other elements is increasing in Chrome and IE browser.
But in Mozilla browser only text size is getting increased on zooming. Is there any Moz property to increase the size of Checkboxes and Radio bUttons on zooming in Mozilla.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: This is browser functionality and you can't change it. Why does size matters  when you are zooming?

Comment: @Manwal I want common UI change on zooming for all browsers. So I want to fix it for Mozilla. Is there any way to fix it via CSS.

Comment: @Web34 at regular percentage you can maintain common but i don't think so for zoom you can maintain same with css.